# ExtJS Dynamically add event handler to Column Editor

Tags: extjs

I want to dynamically add an event handler to column editor on load. It is before any data is populated in the grid. I am not able to find 'on' method on the column's editor property(column.editor.on) like i find on normal combo box. I am using latest ExtJS 6 version . I have defined the column like

```
    {
        xtype: "gridcolumn",
        text: "Available?",
        draggable: false,
        lockable: false,
        hideable: false,
        dataIndex: "Availablility",
        editor: {
            xtype: "combobox",
            forceSelection: true,
            typeAhead: true,
            store: [["Y","Yes"],["N","No"],["U","Not known"]],
            queryMode: "local",
        }
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I assume that editor combobox is initialized later when we have data and we try to edit on the grid. But I want to set some events dynamically on the load of grid. Is there a way to do so?

**Update:** The 'on' method becomes available when we try to edit a row but it is not available on initial load of grid. Isn't there a way to temporarily initialize editing plugin to attach event handler before the data loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can offer you two solutions:

1. Add event handlers via [`listeners`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-listeners) config of your editor (actually [`Ext.util.Observable.on`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-on) is alias for [`Ext.util.Observable.addListener`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-addListener) and `listeners` property use `addListeners`).

   > A config object containing one or more event handlers to be added to this object during initialization. This should be a valid listeners config object as specified in the addListener example for attaching multiple handlers at once.
2. Listen for this combos events in your controller, like

   'myGrid combo[name=myCombo]': {
       change: this.myHandler
   }

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The first approach is more relevant for me as we have a custom layer over Ext Js framework. Although it answers my original question, one thing i want to ask is that when i use 'on' method, i specify the scope for each event handler. In this case, would the scope be common for multiple listeners or i can define scope for each listener separately. Sorry for my limited knowledge on extjs.

Comment: The scope is common for all listeners since its just closures and you define it in the same place in the code. If you ask about `this` reference in a handler function (defaults to the object which fired the event) you can change scope with `scope` property of listeners config. Check `addListener` description - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-addListener

Comment: Thanks again. But i guess we can choose this mechanism as specified in docs and specify different scope for each listener `{ fn: func, scope: this }`

Comment: Yup, I meantioned it - "you can change scope with scope property of listeners config". But its true if under "scope" you mean handler function `this` reference. If under "scope" you mean visibility of variables - its common for all handler functions unless you define it in different places in your code and pass as reference in the `fn` property.